# Quotes conflict when span added with paste

Tags: json, paste, node-webkit

A contenteditable p in a node-webkit window document. Context menu allows cut, copy and paste. When pasting, a span element is added, viz:`<span style="white-space: normal; display: inline !important;">pasted text</span>`. The problem is that the original text is imported from a JSON object and is contained in "" and hence a quotes conflict. I can solve this by the old split and join trick but it seems pretty naff.

Questions:

Why is the span given a style?

Is there a way to import text from JSON to avoid this `<p>"Imported text"</p>`

Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: *Why is the span given a style?:* probably cause you are copying rich formatted text, check if it happens when you paste plain text, say from a text editor as emacs, notepad etc.

Comment: Yes but who decided `!important` for example. I really only asked in case the style thing could be eliminated in due course. It does not seem to serve any purpose other than irritate ... me at least!